# SQL server 2005 - grouping values, display only changes

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I'm trying to group a set of values, but I only want to display the values if there was a change.

Some example data

```
value | date_loaded | 
  1   |  2012-03-07 |
  1   |  2012-03-06 |
  1   |  2012-03-05 |
  3   |  2012-03-04 |
  4   |  2012-03-03 |
  1   |  2012-03-02 |
```

So I would like to display the latest value, with it's earliest date, e.g.

```
value | date_loaded | 
  1   |  2012-03-05 |
  3   |  2012-03-04 |
  4   |  2012-03-03 |
  1   |  2012-03-02 |
```

What is the best way to go about this? Would it be possible to do an if statement? If value 1 is different to value 2, +1 to "change" ? Therefore I'd be able to group the values by "change1", "change2" etc.?

Comment: hmm, I do have an auto generated rownumber

Comment: any joy? hope that made sense.

Comment: Can you use an unambiguous date format like `YYYY-MM-DD`? I can't tell if those are consecutive days or the 3rd of each month. Also can you describe what you want if there are more rows there (e.g. `1 | 1/03/12`)? Do you only care about the newest one not being repeated?

Comment: The date format is actually datetime 07/03/2012 12:46:48, but the dates used there are the 5th March 2012, 4th March 2012.

I'm mostly concerned with showing the values when different from their previous value, but being able to order it by date would be a plus.

Comment: That is not a datetime format, that is British English / Canadian etc. format. If you just say `SELECT datetime_col FROM table` you will not get it as `07/03/2012` (though that may be the way you see it if you print or your client application has otherwise converted it to a string based on your local settings). And you shouldn't want that anyway - see how I was confused about what your dates meant?

Comment: Okay I will ensure that is clearer in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a common table expression to include a sequential row number based on date_loaded, and then use that in a self-join, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    value INT,
    date_loaded DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1,'2012-03-7')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1,'2012-03-6')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1,'2012-03-5')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (3,'2012-03-4')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (4,'2012-03-3')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1,'2012-03-2')

;WITH cte AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_loaded) AS n, value, date_loaded FROM #temp)
SELECT t2.value, t2.date_loaded
FROM cte t2 LEFT JOIN cte t1 ON t2.n = t1.n + 1
WHERE t2.value <> ISNULL(t1.value, -1)

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Hmm I have modified the code a bit but that but it does not appear to work, nor does the example with the temp table (getting error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ','."

Comment: @Rexxo That was 2008 syntax... I updated it to 2005; can you try that again?

Comment: Ah! That's exactly it! I've in putted it with my code as well it and it works a charm. Thanks to both Peter and @MichaelFredrickson