# SQL server 2005 grouping values, display only changes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Posting this again as I've made some updates.

I'm trying to group a set of values, but I only want to display the values if there was a change.

Imagine that the value is fluctuating, ranging from 1, to 4, to 3, to 1, to 1 and to 1 again.

Some example data

```
value | date_loaded | 
  1   |  2012-03-07 |
  1   |  2012-03-06 |
  1   |  2012-03-05 |
  3   |  2012-03-04 |
  4   |  2012-03-03 |
  1   |  2012-03-02 |
```

I want to display each of the values in order of which they fluctuated, but group them together. So you would only see in order, 1, 4, 3, 1, rather then the three 1's most recently.

So I would like to display the latest value, with it's earliest date, e.g.

```
value | date_loaded | 
  1   |  2012-03-05 |
  3   |  2012-03-04 |
  4   |  2012-03-03 |
  1   |  2012-03-02 |
```

What is the best way to go about this? Would it be possible to do an if statement? If value 1 is different to value 2, +1 to "change" ? Therefore I'd be able to group the values by "change1", "change2" etc.?

Comment: Should value '1' be in the result set twice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL server 2005 - grouping values, display only changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600766/sql-server-2005-grouping-values-display-only-changes)

Comment: @Michael -same poster and he's said he's reposting

Comment: It would be better to edit your previous question than to post a new question on the same issue...

Comment: ur last row with id 1 is confusing a bit

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained it to well (I'll update it) but imagine that the value is fluctuating, ranging from 1, to 4, to 3, to 1, to 1 and to 1 again.

I want to display each of the values in order of which they fluctuated, but group them together. So you would only see in order, 1, 4, 3, 1, rather then the three 1's most recently.

Comment: You question is crystal clear now. +1. Tisk tisk for repost, but meh.  Check if my answer helps @Rexxo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
;WITH data AS
(
SELECT 1 as [value],'2012-03-07' as date
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'2012-03-06'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'2012-03-05'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'2012-03-04'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'2012-03-03'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'2012-03-02'
)
,data2 AS
(
SELECT 
[Value]
,date
,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as row1
FROM data
)
,data3 AS
(
SELECT * 
, row1 - row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Value]) as row2
from data2
)
SELECT 
MIN([Value]) AS [Value]
,MIN(Date) as Date
FROM data3
GROUP BY [Value] - row2
ORDER BY MIN(row1)
```

Comment: Temp tables to the rescue! Nice @Davin. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT VALUE,MIN(date_loaded)
FROM  YOURTABLE
GROUP BY VALUE;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just group everything into their respective values and therefore not with every change?

All I would get is 

      1   |  2012-03-05 |
      3   |  2012-03-04 |
      4   |  2012-03-03 |

Answer (score 1):

This solution is kinda complicated, but might just do the trick.  Unfortunately, I don't have all the code off the top of my head, but here is a concept approach for starters:

First, you make a temp table select that includes a row_counter.  Something like so:

```
(SELECT value, date_loaded, row_number() over (partition by date_loaded) as rowNum FROM yourTable) as tempTable1
```

Then use some sort of a while loop that iterates based on the number of rows (tempTableCount) that the temp table above has (tempTable1). This loop would iterate through this temp table one row at a time and INSERT the row into a new temp table.  After each insert, you keep track of the previous inserted value and increment the row counter.  If the value changes, then do the insert, else, continue in the loop.

My syntax is probably very far off (sorry, not at a computer with sql on it), but conceptually:

```
WHILE loopRowCount <= tempTableCount
BEGIN

IF(@previousValue <> (SELECT value from tempTable WHERE rowNum = loopRowCount))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tempTable2
    (value, date_loaded)
        (SELECT value, date_loaded FROM tempTable WHERE rowNum = loopRowCount)
END

set @previousValue = (SELECT value FROM tempTable WHERE rowNum = loopRowCount)
loopRowCount = loopRowCount + 1
END
```

Your tempTable2 will contain the desired result, assuming you survive the syntax error barrage. I'll try and clean it up in the morning, but it's the best I got for tonight! Enjoy! xD

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying! Thanks for your help, I'll give it a go.